# Cannot Aggregate Javadocs from Dependency Sources

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, javadoc, maven-plugin

I am trying to generate javadocs that have links pointing to dependency libraries. I have been following [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate-dependency-sources.html) tutorial, and have successfully generated XXX-sources.jar and XXX-javadoc.jar. But I cannot include dependency javadocs into my project, nor can I generate javadocs with valid links to dependency html files.

More specifically, say my project depends on org.foo.bar. The `bar-core-1.0.0-sources.jar` and `bar-core-1.00-javadoc.jar` files are both available in local maven repository (`~/.m2/repository`), and maven is able to resolve them. One of my source files imports the library API:

```
import org.foo.bar.core.Dependency
```

Then, it uses link in its documents:

```
{@link Dependency} and {@link org.foo.bar.core.AnotherDependency AnotherDependency}
```

My pom.xml file is configured as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

[...]

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>javadoc-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>

                        <dependencySourceIncludes>
                          <dependencySourceInclude>org.foo.bar:*</dependencySourceInclude>
                        </dependencySourceIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, I generate the javadoc using:

```
mvn javadoc:jar
```

In the generated javadoc, `@link` to my own project can be correctly converted into an url wrapped with an `<a>` tag. But, Dependency and AnotherDependency are wrapped with `<code>` tag instead of an `<a>` tag.